# If statement with or (||) argument does not work with in_array method

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have this snippet of code

```
public function dynamicSlugAction(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $array1 = ["coffee", "milk", "chocolate", "coca-cola"];
    $array2 = ["water", "juice", "tomato-juice", "ice-tea"];
    if (!in_array($slug, $array1) || !in_array($slug, $array2)) {
        throw new \Exception("The var " . strtoupper($slug) . " is not exist with parameter (slug): " . $slug);
    }
}
```

Even if I write a right value wich exist in array1 or array2 I have the error launched by the **throw new \Exception**.

If I remove the **or clause** in the **if** statement and I write a right value, no error occured but I can't check the second condition.

Where am I wrong in my if statement?

Comment: Change the `OR` for an `AND`

Comment: Thank you to all , I better understand why my code does not work, such a rookie mistake. I will check all your suggestion to better understand AND OR clause in if statement !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use logical and (&&) not or.  You are saying

If $slug isn't in array1 or isn't in array 2, throw the exception.  So to not throw the exception the slug value would need to be in BOTH array 1 and array 2.

What you really want (I assume), if that if the value of slug isn't in either array throw the exception, but if it exists in one of the arrays, do nothing and carry on.  So change your if statement to:

```
if (!in_array($slug, $array1) && !in_array($slug, $array2)) {
  throw new \Exception("The var ".strtoupper($slug)." is not exist with parameter (slug): ".$slug);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you wanna check,if 2 conditions are true then use the logical operator of and(&&).The or operator(||) is to check if either one is true.Just have in mind the Boolean Algebra in order not to lose track.

Or:

```
statment1=true;
statment2=false;
if(statment1=true||statment2=true){do stuff}//it will run because at least one statment is true
```

And:

```
statment1=true;
statment2=false;
if(statment1=true && statment2=true){do stuff}//it wont run because both statments must be true.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!in_array($slug, $array1) || !in_array($slug, $array2))
```

This condition will throw exception if value does not exists in one of arrays. So if your value exists in one array but not in the other, exception will be thrown.

Check out this logical disjunction table on wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_disjunction_.28OR.29

Answer (score 1):

You must use `and` operator:

```
public function dynamicSlugAction(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $array1 = ["coffee", "milk", "chocolate", "coca-cola"];
    $array2 = ["water", "juice", "tomato-juice", "ice-tea"];
    if (!in_array($slug, $array1) and !in_array($slug, $array2)) {
      throw new \Exception("The var ".strtoupper($slug)." is not exist with parameter (slug): ".$slug);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean if `$slug` exist in any of the array then you don't want to throw error then you should use `&&`

```
if (!in_array($slug, $array1) && !in_array($slug, $array2))
```